# Overloading Methods in Java (EMACS)

Tags: java, methods, overloading

I'm fairly new to Java and I've spent several hours trying to figure out this homework question, but I've yet to figure it out.  This is what it is:
Complete the following definitions for the overloaded one-argument static method money that returns a String representing its argument as an amount of money. For example,

if the input is the double 2.5, then it returns the String "$2.50";

if the input is the int 6, then it returns the String "$6.00"; and

if the input is the String "6.125" then it returns the String "$6.13".

So far I have gotten this:

```
    public static String money( int n )
{
  double a = Integer.parseInt(n);
  return money(n);
}

public static String money( double d )
{
  double b = Double.parseDouble(d);
  return money(d);
}

public static String money( String s )
{
  return money(s);
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
  System.out.println( money( 2.5 ) );
}
```

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you!

Comment: What's your problem then? (Although there is an obvious problem, I am not going to tell.  It is your responsibility to ask question clearly)

Comment: All of your methods are calling themselves, therefore creating an infinite loop - rethinking what you want these methods to return.

Comment: Why you still need to parsing a double value that already is double? Same to Int. When you compile the program, the error message should be self explain.

Comment: Your comments about emacs are irrelevant to your question.  Emacs is just a text editor.  Don't blame it for the mistakes in your code.  If you don't like emacs, install / use a different editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the entirety of your code, then the problem is that the syntax is wrong.  Methods need to be declared inside a class.  Check your textbook or lecture notes, or look at the Oracle Java tutorial.

If those are just snippets, then the problem is that your methods are wrong.  Lets start with the first one:

```
    public static String money( int n ) {
        double a = Integer.parseInt(n);
        return money(n);
    }
```

On the second line, you call Integer.parseInt with an `int` argument, but that method requires a `String` argument.  That won't compile.  Also, it doesn't do what you need to do at that point.  The `Integer.parseInt` method converts a `String` to an `int`, but you don't have a string to start with and you don't need to end up with an `int`.

Then on the third line, you **ignore** the value of `a` and recursively call `money(int)` with the original argument.

What the method is apparently supposed to do is to create a **formatted** string, but your code doesn't do that.

---

In hind-sight, those recursive calls could have been generated by the "short-cuts" you were complaining about.  If that is the case, the best thing to do is to 1) delete them and 2) **think** about what your problem statement requires at that point.  (Hint: formatting ...)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I'm having a rough night and realized I'm missing so much haha.  I've gotten it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String money( int n )
{
  n = n * 100;
  double n1 = n / 100;
  String n2 = String.valueOf(n1);
  return n2;
}

public static String money( double d )
{
  d = Math.round(d*100);
  d = d / 100;
  String d1 = String.valueOf(d);
  return d1;
}

public static String money( String s )
{
 double s1 = Double.parseDouble(s);
 s1 = Math.round(s1*100);
 s1 = s1 / 100;
 String s2 = String.valueOf(s1);
 return s2;
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
  System.out.println( money( 12.3456 ) );
}
```